# "Secure Boot dbx Configuration Update" resulting in error on 2018 Razer Blade 15

Tags: updates, 22.04, secure-boot, snap-store

I get this error message when clicking update:

[image: unable to update "secure boot dbx configuration update": message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying]

```
Unable to update "Secure Boot dbx Configuration Update": Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
```

What do I need to do to fix this error and allow the secure boot dbx update to install?

Answer (score 1):

Some machines have occasional issues with firmware updates through the software centre. What I've found (for Dell machines, anyway) is that you can sometimes get around this by using the Terminal.

Here's how:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Refresh `fwupdmgr`:

   ```
   sudo fwupdmgr refresh
   ```
2. Check for available updates:

   ```
   sudo fwupdmgr get-updates
   ```
3. If you see there are updates to be applied, you can do so with:

   ```
   sudo fwupdmgr update
   ```

If the machine asks you to reboot after applying the updates, feel free to do so. Otherwise, you can carry on with your day

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work for me...

Comment: I ended up doing a fresh install of Ubuntu and was allowed to update. Problem solved, kinda.